# How to take out the numerical values from a list of numbers and words in linux

Tags: linux, numeric

I'm a newbie in Linux. I was trying to make a nested if loop inside a for loop and found difficulties taking out the numeric values from a list. My code is

```
 #!/bin/bash
t=`ls ListOfthings`
for i in $t
do
  if "$i" -eq "$i"
 then
    echo hi (for example)
fi
done
```

when I execute this, it said syntax error unexpected token 'done'. I think its some problems related to the `"$i" -eq "$i"`? Is this the right way to identify the numerical items?

For example, from a list `[123 23 63 a.txt b.txt c.sh]`, `123`, `23` and `63` are needed.

Comment: `if [ "$i" -eq "$i" ]`  (good job quoting variables), but `t=\`ls ListOfthings\``, ***Never*** use `for i in $(ls anything)` (which IS what your are doing), see [**Bash Pitfalls #1**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) (there is a reason that is **Pitfall #1**)

Comment: Are `123 23 63 a.txt b.txt c.sh` filenames you capture with `t=\`ls ListOfthings\``?

Comment: To find numerical filenames only, you could use `find .  -maxdepth 1 -name "[0-9][0-9]*"` , for example.

Comment: yes, so we need to use [] for the list?

Answer (score 1):

Try using regex. For example: `egrep '^[0-9]+$' list`

Or if you're using ls: `ls | egrep '^[0-9]+$'`